# Why does the first subview's position of a UIVewController embedded in a UINavigationController get altered?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I've noticed some strange behavior of `UITablesViews` inside a `ViewController` when said `ViewController` is embedded within a `UINavigationController`.  The following is the code of a simple prototype for selecting different `UITableViews` to be shown in a scene excluding the methods for the `TableView` and selecting which view to show.

```
class ChooseTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  var tableViewA: UITableView = UITableView()
  var tableViewB: UITableView = UITableView()

  var colors: [String] = ["red", "blue", "green"]
  var shapes: [String] = ["triangle", "circle", "square"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableViewA.frame       = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200)
    tableViewA.delegate    = self
    tableViewA.dataSource  = self
    tableViewA.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellTableViewA")

    tableViewB.frame       = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200)
    tableViewB.delegate    = self
    tableViewB.dataSource  = self
    tableViewB.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellTableViewB")

    self.view.addSubview(tableViewB)
    self.view.addSubview(tableViewA)
    tableViewB.hidden = true

    let segmentSelectorLabels = ["one", "two"]
    let segmentSelector = UISegmentedControl(items: segmentSelectorLabels)
    segmentSelector.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2 - 50, self.view.frame.height - 100, 100, 40)
    self.view.addSubview(segmentSelector)
    segmentSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    segmentSelector.addTarget(self, action: "chooseTable:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

...
}
```

and here are the results of when `ChooseTableViewController` is not embedded in a `UINavigationController` and when it is

[Simulators results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL86U.jpg)

In another project the behavior can be fixed by simply adding

```
let emptyView:UIView = UIView()
```

and

```
self.view.addSubiew(emptyView)
```

with `emptyView` being the first added subview.  This is a hackney solution to having the `UITableViews` placed in their proper position.  Any insight to this behavior is appreciated.

Comment: Was this view controller instantiated from storyboard?

Comment: @ kirander Yes it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets" for the viewcontroller in the Attributes inspector or do it in code:

`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` (Obj-C)
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` (Swift)

[image: View Controller]

some more explanation:

if this property is set to YES / true the viewcontroller - as the name says - automatically adjusts the insets for the **first** scrollview in its view hierarchy. this can be helpful if your scrollview / tableview / textview / webview takes up the whole screen and parts of it are normally hidden by the statusbar / navigationbar / tabbar or toolbar. then those insets make your content appear below the top bars / above the bottom bars. this though only happens when the scrollview / ... is the **TOP MOST** subview in the view hierarchy (= the subview at index 0). to make things clearer i uploaded four examples:

1. property set to YES / true and two textviews in the view hierarchy (at index 0 and 1): as you can see the insets are only set for the **first** scrollview
   [image: 01]
2. property set to NO / false and two textviews in the view hierarchy (at index 0 and 1): as you can see no insets are set at all
   [image: 02]
3. property set to YES / true, a button (subview at index 0) and two textviews (at index 1 and 2): as you can see no insets are set at all although the property is YES / true. that is because no scrollview is the **TOP MOST** subview in the view hierarchy.
   [image: 03]
4. property set to YES / true an a textview in the view hierarchy at index 0 taking up the whole screen: as you can see although the textview takes up the whole screen (starts at 0,0) the text is not hidden by the status- / navigationbar because the viewcontroller automatically adjusted the textview's (scrollview's) inset.
   [image: 04]

i hope i could help making things a bit clearer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the two concise solutions to the predicament and if you can, please explain how the `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController` make use of `UIEdgeInsets`.  It's not pleasant having Storyboards hide so much.

Comment: After reading through you're edit I was led to Apple's UIViewController Class Reference where you nailed it.  Adding the respective syntax and code for Obj-C and Swift is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set table view's frame origin y-positions to 0. Find "Extended Edges" settings for this view controller in storyboard and turn off "Under Top Bars".

Comment: While the `UIViewController` was instantiated through the storyboards the `UITableView`'s are not.

Comment: I know that. I mean to change frames in code. Or do you mean something else?